# Why does <Leader>l open my folds?

Tags: key-bindings

Despite there being no mention on the keystroke `<Leader>l` in my `.vimrc`, this combination opens the current fold on my installation of `vim` and `gvim`.

It's not mentioned under `:map`. Is it a standard thing or might it be due to a plug-in?

Comment: If your cursor is on a fold, pressing `l` will open it.  I don't think the leader key does anything in this case.

Comment: Check the mapping by using `:verbose <leader>l` to see if there is a map.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `<Leader>l`isn't mapped to anything, than this is effictivly the same as the motion `l`. And this will open your folds. If you don't want this, tune the `'foldopen'` setting like this:

```
:set foldopen-=hor
```